# iphone and ipad app for emails that supports colors, fonts, etc

Tags: ios, software-recommendation

I can easily bold, italicize, and underline words...but I really want to be able to style my emails.

Are there mail apps that:
*  support colors (mandatory)
*  free or low cost preferred

Nice to have are:
* full "html editor" built into the email client to change fonts, font size, color, alignment, etc.

Can someone recommend options?

Answer (score 2):

I do this so seldom, that I use another editor to compose what I need and then copy/paste. On the iPad, you have split screen so you can edit in one larger pane and then compose the main in a smaller pane.

Here are my editing apps of choice:

- Notes - free and powerful
- Coda - HTML powerhouse
- GoodNotes - more for note taking, but handwriting to text is so awesome, I had to include it
- Drafts - pure writing power
- Pages - also free and powerful

Each has different strengths.